# How to write a Class object back to .class file?

Tags: java

I know we can load a Object from .class file and my question is how to do it reversely.
I use `Class.forName("classname")` to get a Class object and how can I write this back to the .class file?
Serialization class is not the point for this issue because the loaded file may not be implement Serializable interface.

The reason why I ask this is I need convert Class object to java source text string. If anyone knows how to convert Object class to source directly, it might be great helpful.

Comment: Are you asking about decompiling something? As in taking a .class file, and getting the .java "equivalent"?

Comment: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Comment: if Austin is right then you can go for lots of free tool available which convert.class to .java..ex DJ (DJ Java Decompiler )..

Comment: *"The reason why I ask this is I need recompile the .class file to source text."* That has nothing to do with writing back to the `.class` file, and it's called *decompilation* when you're going in that direction. The Java VM doesn't have decompilation built-in. There are several decompilers available as external tools (which, of course, you can call from Java just like any other external tool).

Comment: @Austin yes decompile, Input: Class object, Output: java source String, if negative,  firstly from Class object to temp .class file, then use DJ or something from .class file to .java file.

Comment: Then in that case, checkout some free Decompile tools that are out there.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yes, but firstly I need to write the Class object which get from runtime `Class.forName("classname")` to .class temp file, then I can decompile it. I asked for how to do this.

Comment: @JerryCai: (Actually, that *wasn't* what you asked. It may have been what you *meant* to ask.) But more to the point, you don't need to; you can just decompile the original `.class` file, unless you have some (unspecified) limitation, such as the `.class` is coming from a network resource.

Comment: -1. It's obvious your question is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add functions etc to a class you can use.

http://www.jboss.org/javassist

example:

```
 clazz = fullclass name, method = "public void doxxx(){ int x =0;x++}"

private static void createMethod(String clazz,String method){
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        try {
            Class<?> class1 =  Class.forName(clazz);
            class1.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
            pool.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(class1));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CtClass pt;
        try {

            pt = pool.get(clazz);



            CtMethod m = CtNewMethod.make(method, pt);
            pt.addMethod(m);
            pt.writeFile();
            pt.toClass();

        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CannotCompileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm reading doc of Javassist, quick check: Can I use this tool to read a class object at runtime and modify some value of properties and write back to JVM at runtime?

Comment: I am not sure if you can read what is currently in the .class file as normal .java code. however you can overwrite a method if you like to, but what you have todo is rename the oldone first to something diffrent.